# How to str_replace a txt file with newlines using PHP

Tags: php, file, fopen, str-replace

I have a text file with the following 2 lines

```
woof
woof99
```

I then have this code where it's supposed to take the username, example woof and take it out and replace it with nothing.

```
$file = fopen("../UsersProfile/".$MyUsername."/otherfiles/Following.txt","a") or die("Unable to open file");
    $content = file_get_contents("../UsersProfile/".$MyUsername."/otherfiles/Following.txt");
    $newcontent = str_replace($Username."\n", '', "$content");
    file_put_contents("../UsersProfile/".$MyUsername."/otherfiles/Following.txt", "$newcontent");
    fclose($file);
```

the text file will then look like this with one line now.

```
woof99
```

the issue that I am having is that it isn't working for some reason. I believe it worked before but for some reason now it isn't. Is there an easier way to do this? 
Thanks!

Edit: I found out what I needed to do I need to do `\r\n`

Comment: Do you have error logging turned on? Have you confirmed that `file_get_contents()` is succeeding, i.e. not returning `FALSE`? Have you confirmed that `file_put_contents()` is not returning `FALSE`?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is returning the data, file_put_contents is working, the issue is the str_replace

Answer (score -1):

```
$newcontent = str_replace($Username."\n", '', $content);
```

Just turn this **"$content"** to this **$content** :D

Comment: That won't make a difference, as they are both interpreted as the same string.

Comment: $newcontent = str_replace($Username." ", '', $content); 
 worked for me!

Comment: Your code won't work though because it leaves the line break there and doesn't remove it. 
It'll turn out to be 
`\n
woof99` but instead the whole text file needs to just be `woof99` because the user `woof` was taken out

Comment: sorry get that but send me your error code correctly the nwill help you